# Using echo to alter a files md5

Tags: io-redirection, echo

I need to alter the md5 for some of my files, I was told to run the following

```
echo >> /path/to/file.iso
```

I was just wondering, What does actually do to the file. It seems to work and change the MD5 but is there a chance this could make a file corrupt ?

Comment: That command will append a newline character to the file. Whether it "corrupts" the file depends on what the applications that read the file expect when reading and interpreting the file.

Answer (score 1):

As Janis says, it appends a newline. Anything that changes the existing exact sequence of bytes in the file will cause the MD5 checksum to be altered.

The ISO image will still work as it's an image of an ISO9660 (CDROM) filesystem, and the filesystem know what its bounds are and won't get confused by extra data beyond the end of a filesystem.

However some CD burning tools may be confused by the fact that the image is not a multiple of 2048 bytes (the native block size of a CDROM), and refuse to burn the image; others may just give a warning or ignore it, some badly written tool may even give an error at the end when it tries to write an incomplete block.

Other types of files may give differing results. E.g. a ZIP file has its index at a fixed offset from the end of the file, so appending some extra bytes may lead to the index not being found anymore, resulting in what appears to be a corrupted ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried running it several times on a few test files of .iso and .rar and they still seem to work ok. Does that mean if the md5 is changed again several times later it will continue to work or will it eventually be too many?

Comment: It will keep on working. My only concern with `.iso` files was possible block size issues, if one extra byte doesn't matter then two or three etc. won't matter either.